# Simplify the code

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review, map

I have a function that grabs the second part of the list and change it to times,

```
mylist = {{{y1, y2, y3}, {y3, y4, y5}}, {{w1, w2, w3}, {w4, w5, w6}}};
g[x_] := x /. List -> Times
Map[g, mylist, {2}]
```

I wrote it above, but I think I should be able to make it much simpler code using @ # and &. Any suggestion?

Comment: FWIW: you don't need to define `g`: you can use `/.` as an operator directly: `Map[ReplaceAll[List -> Times], mylist, {2}]`, or even `Map[# /. List -> Times &, mylist, {2}]`.

Comment: Idiomatic way is to use: `Apply[Times, mylist, {2}]`. It is short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you appear to want to multiply the list only when all of its elements are atomic, how about just

```
mylist /. {s__?AtomQ} :> Times[s]
```

It appears to be the most direct translation of your thought.

Answer (score 16):

```
☺lookMaNoLetters☺ = 1 ## & @@@ # & /@ # &;

☺lookMaNoLetters☺ @ mylist
```

> {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}

Further variations:

```
☺lookKidNoLettersOrNumbers☺ = # ##2 & @@@ # & /@ # &;

☺ApplyTimesAtLevel2☺ = # ##2 & @@ ## &[#, {2}] &;

☺InCaseYouLikeInfix☺ = # ~ (# ##2 & @@ ## &) ~ {2} &;

☺IfYouLikeVerbose☺ = Map @* MapApply @ Times
```

You can use as many `@`s as you like:

```
☺♬♪♫♪☺ = ## & @@@ (## & @@@ ## & @@@ 1 ## & @@@ {##} & @@@ {##} & /@ #) &;

☺♬♪♫♪☺ @ mylist
```

> {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}

Comment: I'd add a disclaimer suggesting OP should not actually code this way...

Comment: What a fun answer! I already accept the answer, but it is amazing, and very helpful for me to understand the language. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
Times @@@ # & /@ mylist
(*    {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}    *)
```

Comment: This seems less clear and less general than `Apply[Times, mylist, {2}]` or ...`{-2}`.

Comment: @lirtosiast oh yes for sure, but the OP was specifically asking for @ # & gobbledygook :-) Ideally there would be a `@@@@` operator for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear and nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

Another way to view your function is as a generalized inner product:

```
Inner[Times, mylist, {1, 1, 1}, Times]
{{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Map[Times[Sequence @@ #] &] /@ mylist
(* {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Apply` can be used with level specificator in the same way as `Map`:

```
Apply[Times, mylist, {2}]
```

> {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}

Answer (score 3):

If `mylist` is a depth-three rectangular array, the following will work; if it is also packed, this will minimally unpack and produce a packed array:

```
Times @@ Transpose[mylist, {2, 3, 1}]
(*  {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}  *)
```

More obfuscatory fun:

```
Block[{★},
 ★ /: {x__★} := Block[{★ = # &}, 1 x];
 Function[s, ★@s, Listable]@mylist
 ]
(*  {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}  *)
```

Comment: You could also compile for no unpacking (`_Real` or `_Integer`, but in separate functions): `cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 3}}, Times @@ Transpose[a, {2, 3, 1}]]; cf@myarray`.  Or force `Apply` to compile with `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "ApplyCompileLength" -> 0];`.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{{y1, y2, y3}, {y3, y4, y5}}, {{w1, w2, w3}, {w4, w5, w6}}};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[Times] /@ list
```

{{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{{y1, y2, y3}, {y3, y4, y5}}, {{w1, w2, w3}, {w4, w5, w6}}};
```

Using `MapApply` and `Transpose` as follows:

```
Times @@ Transpose@{##} & @@@ list

(*{{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}*)
```

Or using `Replace` at level `2`:

```
Replace[list, v_ :> Times @@ v, {2}]

(*{{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = {{{y1, y2, y3}, {y3, y4, y5}}, {{w1, w2, w3}, {w4, w5, w6}}};

rule = x_?VectorQ :> Times @@ x;
mylist /. rule
```

> {{y1 y2 y3, y3 y4 y5}, {w1 w2 w3, w4 w5 w6}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map`:

```
Map[Times[Delete[#,0]]&, mylist, {2}]
```

(* {{y1 y2 y3,y3 y4 y5},{w1 w2 w3,w4 w5 w6}} *)

Comment: +1, Very nice and flexible (replace `0` with `1` etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Been a while since I coded in Wolfram...

```
Times @@ mylist[[2]]
```

So long that I had to look up indexing.

Comment: Almost forgot that Mathematica had a nifty set of ways to specify indexing. Ones that I tried to copy.

Comment: This produces `{w1 w4, w2 w5, w3 w6}`, which is not close to what is sought.  (It's good site practice to include the output of your code, when it's not too long.)  Makes you wonder about the upvote, though, doesn't it.